# How to launch the camera application in landscape mode and keep it that way in iphone?

Tags: iphone, ip-camera

I wish to launch the camera in my app but keep it in landscape mode only... is it possible?

Comment: Hi Ankit....same thing i need to implement in my project.Do you have any solution or any ideas how you implementes in your project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you check the default iphone camera and you put it in the landescape mode only the icons of flash and other items comes in the landscape mode and the white bar always remaining on left side of the camera app so i think we cann't  put that bar in the landsecape mode and remaining thing you can do in landescape by autorotate interface doing yes.